# Jackson - DTO int to String conversion

Tags: java, jackson, dto

Working on a REST client that calls another server which returns the following object:

```
public class ObjectOriginal {
   private int id;
   private String name;

   // constructor/getters/setters
}
```

I need to obfuscate the id. To do so I'm using an already existing service that transforms the id into a unique generated String so that the person calling my service doesn't know the REAL id but can still request info about it with the unique string.

So I'm basically trying to return to the caller this object:

```
public class ObjectNew {
   private String id;
   private String name;

   // constructor/getters/setters
}
```

Do I need to have a copy of ObjectOriginalDTO + create a ObjectNew DTO + create a mapper to go from one to the other.
Or can I configure Jackson to deserialize the id field as a String and not an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using your own Serializer/Deserializer.
You have to implement your Serializer/Deserializer that will extends respectively `BeanSerializerModifier/BeanDeserializerModifier` and configuring your Module with them for instance Or use the annotation base solution as explained in this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization), there are plenty of references on the web for such a thing. then you'll have more controlle over the way to map your `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have custom deserializer you can have:

```
public class ObjectNewDto {
   private String id;
   private String name;

   // constructor/getters/setters
}
```

and  another object:

```
public class ObjectOriginal {
   private int id;
   private String name;
 // construxtor/getters/settes
}
```

Now after validating ObjectNewDto you can map it via your obfuscator service into ObjectOriginal , then validate this Object original and so on...